# Session Start Custom Function in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am rookie to asp.net . I am developing a application in asp.net 3.5 , on that i need to start a timer ticker whenever the site is requested to open,  and ends whenever the page is closed . Heard about the Global.asax file . But , is there any possibility to call the function of another class from Global.asax . Any one help me

Comment: What do you mean: the page is closed ? closed from the user you mean ?

Comment: from session_start to session_end ... how to access a function of another class placed inside app_code

Comment: The session_end have not trigger in most of case, so you can have a start, but need different approach for the end. Also a user with out cookies (like google bot) starts a session in each request. You can end up with 20+ timers but only with 2 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can instantiate the `classes` and call `methods` from the handlers of Application event file.

```
public class Foo {
   public string bar(){ 
     return "Hello";
   }
}
```

Create instance of Foo:

```
Foo foo=new Foo();
var value=foo.bar();
```

Comment: Could you give me a sample snippet

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call the function of `class` file by creating its `object`